# What is the current status of the zero trust model?

Tags: zero-trust

I read of the apprarently ambitious goals of the "zero trust model". Has it found success in practice or encountered problems? A link that may be useful is: https://www.forrester.com/The+Security+Architecture+And+Operations+Playbook+For+2016/-/E-PLA300

Comment: Care to link the paper or article you read? Hard to discuss the details in context without it.

Comment: @Polynomial: I read a paper in German by R. Rieken in C. Linnhoff-Popien et al. (Eds.) Marktplaetze im Umbruch (Springer, 2015), which mentions that the idea of zero trust model leads to an ongoing project of the German Ministry of Economy and Energy. That paper doesn't give much details IMHO. But I have updated my OP with a link that I just found and that presumably could be of some use to you.

Comment: If it's an emerging concept in security theory, the number of people who know anything about is is probably quite small. You may be better off directly communicating with the paper authors via email.

Comment: @Polynomial: I found that already in 2013 forrester.com has submitted a document to NIST and that is available at: https://csrc.nist.gov/cyberframework/rfi_comments/040813_forrester_research.pdf So I surmise that the idea isn't extremely novel today and very possibly some experts may be quite familiar with at least something of that genre.

Comment: @Polynomial: There could be a problem in accessing the link, in which case please change https to http.